# Vue.js 2 axios computed value returning "invalid date"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am new to Vue.js, trying to understand computed values. In particular, I am returning json data from my REST API, and in that data is a field called date that is in unixtime (ie `1486231256`). I want to transform that field to human readable, but the app is returning `invalid date`. Here is my code:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
  data: () => ({
    errors: [],
    posts: []
  }),

  // Fetches posts when the component is created.
  created () {
    axios.get('https://example.com/api/v1/?uid=1', {
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.posts = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  },
  computed: {
    unixform () {
      return moment(this.posts.date, 'X').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I don't think moment is the problem here, because if I change the function's return to simply `this.posts.date` or `this.date`, I get an error of `undefined`. So somehow, I am not accessing that property, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: What does your response looks like ? Is it an array or object ? You've declared `posts` to be an array.

Comment: posts returns an array with 59 objects inside of it. inside each object are a number of fields including `date`, but I get the exact same error if I define posts as an object {}

Comment: Then `this.posts.date` is wrong. `posts` is an array and property `date` does not exists on array. You need to iterate over the array `posts` to get the individual objects and call the moment function on each date value.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think moment is the problem here, because if I change the
>   function's return to simply this.posts.date or this.date, I get an
>   error of undefined. So somehow, I am not accessing that property, and
>   I can't figure out why.

Indeed... Your problem is not even related to Vue or Axios, but to Vanilla JS.

The AJAX response gives you an array of objects similar to this:

```
let posts = [
  { date: '1486231256' },
  { date: '1502199613' }
];
```

To get the dates, you cannot simply do `posts.date` because `posts` is an array! As suggested by **@abhishekkannojia**, you have to loop through the array:

```js
let posts = [
  { date: '1486231256' },
  { date: '1502199613' }
];

for (const post of posts) {
  console.log(moment.unix(post.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I totally see what you mean, and your logic is correct as far as it goes but that leaves me wondering in the context of Vue.js (or axios) how to use a computed function to filter output on part of the loop output in my template. It seems like overkill to loop over the entire thing, only to loop over it again in my template.

Comment: I do not understand why you absolutely want to use computed properties... You can make your AJAX calls in regular methods and use custom filters for dates. You could also use vue-moment or vue-i18n to handle your dates properly. ;)

Comment: I am using vue moment, but need to apply it to dates either: before they get to vue-data-tables, or in the data response from the axios call. I can make a regular loop and my moment filter works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found a workaround by replacing my vue-data-tables with vuetify data-tables, which allows me to use my standard filters.